# How can I have my UIGestureRecognizer attached to my view and apply its effects on another item

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My issue is that when scaling UIimages, the images eventually get too small touch, rotate and resize.

My thought was to attach the recognizer to the background view and have it pass the actions being done to the views on top of it.

So say I have View A as the background.

View B, C, and D are on top.

Currently, B, C and D have recognizers that handle pinch, pan and rotate.

I would like that recognizer to be attached to View A.

If B has focus, pinching on the display sends the gesture to A and A applies it to B and so on.

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
//    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    UIView *tmp = [imagesToRender lastObject];
    tmp.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;

}
```

The commented out line above was the way I was resizing all of the images. However, since the recognizer is now attached to View A. I had to get the item I want to resize. Which I have denoted with UIView.

The resizing works. However it undoes other transforms. Say, I had rotated the item before resizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
//    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    UIView *tmp = selectedItem;
    tmp.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(tmp.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;

}
```

I was able to accomplish this by changing the CGAffineTransformScale and use the tmp image to maintain the past scales

Answer (score 0):

Try to Add a transparent (alpha = 0) view-E on top of all other. attache your gestureReconizer to this View-E (this is possible as it is on top), and send to other based on your logic...

Comment: what about if you comment the line `// recognizer.scale = 1;`

Comment: If you don't what the scale to be reseted each time you re-start pinch, instead of commenting the line like proposed in previous comment, just adjust your transform like this : `tmp.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(tmp.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);. now your transform is base on previous transform of the selected view and not based on background view. Hop this solve your problem.